# use i option to add text as the first item on a line

Tags: sed

I need to add a word before the line starts, but I want to do that for every line which the text has.

If I have `sample/text/` and I want to add `data/sample/txt`, how can I do that?

I have tried sed `i` command in several ways but none of it works.

Comment: Please show us what command did you try and What are your input and desired output?

Comment: I have used: sed -i '1 i\data' samples.new.txt and sed -i -e '1idata\' samples.new.txt

Comment: I would like to get data/sample/text rather than sample/text that I  have now..

Comment: `sed`'s command `i \ ` is meant for inserting text with embedded newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` you can substitute the beginning of a line with `'s[^sample/text[data/sample/text[g'`

The `^` denotes the start of a line.

The substitute command allowes you to use a different character to seperate the options from the default `/` to, in this case, `[` which is sometimes handy if you have the `/` character in your search or replacement text.

Before you use the `-i` flag to perform the inline replacement, first try this on a file and redirect it's output to see if it has the desired output.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this won't work again..

Comment: I just changed something and it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: +1 but that's a strange choice for a delimiter.

Comment: Plus consider using `&` in the replacement (DRY): `s[^sample/text[data/&['. Note that you're anchoring the expression, so no point in using the `g` flag -- it can match at  most once.

Answer (score 0):

Use **AWK**.

If your file is `textfile` and you want to add the text `newtext` to every line you can use:

```
 awk '{print "newtext ",$0}' textfile
```